# How to terminate execution

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core API, which consumes Webhooks from Shopify. For example, if user places an Order in Shopify, I will receive an Webhook payload (a HTTP POST request) to endpoint `myApi.com/shopify/webhooks/orders/created`.

Tricky part is Shopify timeout: Shopify expect response to its Webhook calls in max **5 seconds**.

In most cases, ASP.NET Core API process Webhook payload in less than 5 seconds and everything is fine. However, in some cases (as cold starts etc) execution will take more than 10 seconds.

Shopify will, in this case, mark Webhook call as failed and repeat after minute or two. However, I can see in my logs that processing of first request continues after 5 secs and order is successfully created. After 15 seconds.

This behaviour results in duplicates (and some other issues).

I am looking for a way how limit handle this situation:

- either limit ASP.NET Core execution to 5 secs (kill processing after 5 secs)
- or break execution of ASP.NET Core controllers after certain time or cancel event.

My ASP.NET Core API is hosted as AWS Lambda. First attempt was to limit Lambda execution to 5 or 6 secs, however, this causes that API is never even started due to typical coldstarts which takes more than 10 seconds and thus are never processed.

Is cancellation token designed for this? I suppose cancellation token is used only if Shopify regularly terminates HTTP call after 5 seconds.

Thanks for any advice

EDIT:
Added some more details, log from CloudWatch
[image]

See the first execution: it took totally 14 seconds, from which first call to SQS from MessageQueuePublisher (which basically wraps Amazon.SQS.IAmazonSQS) took 5 seconds.

Comment: Can you not just check for duplicates ? surely the webhooks come with an id

Comment: Take a look at this library https://www.hangfire.io/. The recommendation from Shopify is that you respond early acknowling the request has been received correctly and process it out of the httpcontext (after having responded 200)

Comment: Thanks! @MichaelRandall I can make processing idempotent, indeed, but that will require dbo & VPC, which will result in even slower execution and increased costs.

Comment: @PabloRecalde yes exactly as you said, I am re-writing API to use message queue which will do the job and API will response with 200 as soon as possible. However, still not enough, I am failing on that I have duplicate events in queue due to what I have written above